# Get text value from one div to input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how can i get each value from my divs to my input? Here is my code - I've managed to get all the values but i cannot get individual values?

[my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8nqwmcu/) and code below -

```
<input class=".ui-spinner"></input>

$(".cn-wrapper li span").click(function () {
        var textValue = $('.cn-wrapper li span').text();
        $('.ui-spinner').val(textValue);
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove dot in Html `<input class=".ui-spinner"></input>`, and use **this** for current clicked element

```
  $(".cn-wrapper li span").click(function () {
        var textValue = $(this).text();
        $('.ui-spinner').val(textValue);
    });
```

**[updated Fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/t8nqwmcu/1/)**

Comment: OK, what is the relation b/w  *cn-wrapper li span* ,*ui-spinner class*, it has 3 class  with  same class name, what would you want , or ask new question

Comment: this is what I mean - so depending which input is selected - the value is displayed http://jsfiddle.net/fmLjr5cf/

Answer (score 0):

```js
   $(".cn-wrapper li span").on("click", function () {
        var textValue = $(this).text();
        $('.ui-spinner').val(textValue);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cn-wrapper" id="cn-wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span >50</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><span>100</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><span>200</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><span >300</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><span >400</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><span >500</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><span>600</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><span>700</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="#"><span>Set</span></a></li>



            </ul>
        </div>

<input class="ui-spinner"></input>
```